# What is the code that I need if I want to fill the solid background color of my PowerPoint?

Tags: colors, background, powerpoint, rgb

Sub Hex

.Background

.BackColor

RGB=RGB(0,0,0)

End With

End Sub

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide more information and some real code instead of gobbledegook. Are you trying to change the background for the entire presentation, or just some of the layouts, or just a selected slide?

Answer (score 0):

The code's sytax is incorrect. You have an `End With`, but no `With`.

You can change the background of your slide-master with the following macro:

`ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,0)`

Comment: Setting the Office Theme only changes the appearance of the program interface, not the presentation itself.

Comment: I know @JohnKorchok . I am sorry .- it was a bit sarcastic because he wrote "background color of my PowerPoint?"  I apologize for that. The code for changing the background is also in my answer ;-)

Comment: Please format your code using the ``` symbol. It helps us to distinguish the code.